# Linechart on click jQuery not working angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a linechart with some data, my ultimate goal is if you click on a dot you go to the corresponding page.

This is my page: https://gyazo.com/0a7ace53799f3b72253789a934dd6634

This is my html markup:

```
        <linechart id="chart"
            data="data" 
            options="options" 
            mode="" 
            width="" 
            height="500"  ng-init="onInit()">
        </linechart>
```

When I try to select the dots with:

```
       var dot = $('.dot');
       console.log(dot);
       dot.on('click',function(){
          console.log('test');
       });
```

It can't seem to find it. Even though the html of the loaded page has the dots in circle-tags with classname 'dot'.

Like this: https://gyazo.com/a74d279bbf9acbd8f7a61f9eb9b21164.

Comment: Is the listener in the directive or in the controller?

Comment: it should probably be in  you're directive. Are you not able to use `ng-click`?

Comment: I dont use a directive, what is the advantage of using a directive?
I can use ng-click either, because I can't hardcode the tags since the linechart creates the g-tags etc. automaticly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registerring on 'click' event before elements are builded in DOM by directive.

You should check if element exists, and only after that register on click event.

You can do it using **setInterval** function:

```
var checker = setInterval(checkDot, 50)
function checkDot(){
  if($('.dot').length > 0){
    clearInterval(checker);
    $('.dot').on('click', yourFunction);
  }
}
```

Anyway using jQuery events in angular app is not the best solution.

I would try to find click event functionality in documentation of this 'linechart' directive. If there is not, you can try to modify template of directive by adding `ng-src` or `ng-click` or even just `href` attribute